# Kafka, why do I need to pass the certificate chain and not only the root ca when testing with kafka-console-producer (or Kafkcat)

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, certificate, chain

I have a Kafka cluster which is configured to be used over ssl on port 9093.

In order for me successfully send data on port 9093 I need to pass the certificate chain (intermediate + root CA) (all these are self signed stuff)

```
echo "Hello" | kafkacat -P -b localhost:9095 -t my-topic \
    -X security.protocol=ssl \
    -X ssl.key.location=cert-key.pem \
    -X ssl.ca.location=chain.crt
```

(chain.crt is a file with the rootCA and intermediate cert)

My question is why do I need to issue the full chain and not just the root CA in the ssl.ca.location param ?

Answer (score 1):

`ssl.key.location` is the client's certificate for authenticating to the broker.
`ssl.ca.location` is used by the client to verify the broker's certificate.

Comment: I think OP's question was more about why the value of `ssl.ca.location` needs to be the full chain vs just the root cert. Can the broker be configured to provide the entire chain?